# what approach to use instead of server side Office automation for importing tasks from MSProject

Tags: ms-office, server-side, ms-project, office-automation

I have to open up MSProject file from a different Sharepoint site
and ensure that all the tasks are read from the file and bound to ASP.NET Grid.

I have used the office Interop assemblies and have encountered some errors.

I also came to know that Microsoft doesn't support server side office automation.

Is there any recommended way of achieveing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try Aspose Tasks:
http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.tasks-for-.net/default.aspx

We are using Aspose for Word, Excel and Powerpoint for years. Works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the MPXJ library. There is a .Net version apparently. Probably a heck of a lot lower overhead than Interop assemblies.

http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/index.html